# Is there a module that can "lazy load" content, not just images?

Tags: 7

Utilizing the [JAIL](http://drupal.org/project/jail) module I can lazy load images. Is there any module that lets me do this for content as well (i.e. only load portions of the page that are in the current viewport)?

Comment: check this https://drupal.org/project/nodelazyloader

Answer (score 1):

You can try out [infinite scroll](http://drupal.org/project/views_infinite_scroll). It (lazy)loads the content as you scroll through the page.

Comment: Infinite scroll is great for views pages. Is there anything that can do this to a node?

Comment: Infinite scroll does not work if ajax is enabled in views.

Answer (score 1):

I recently made a jQuery plugin that will "lazy load" anything you want. When the jQuery selector elements come into view of the browser viewport it will for a load event which you can stuff full of jQuery/Javascript goodness.

https://github.com/shrimpwagon/jquery-lazyloadanything

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Node Lazy Loader](https://www.drupal.org/project/nodelazyloader) which lazy loads all nodes in site with multiple nodes in a site.

Comment: This link seems to indeed answer the question, but a longer explanation would help. Especially - how does it work with JAIL?

Comment: The query was how to lazyload content or Is there any module and not Is there any stuff that can lazyload content in sync with JAIL.

Comment: Question asking to recommend module are off topic here. Answering off topic questions, even if they are not closed yet, has some side effects...

Comment: So you mean this question was off topic as it was asking to recommend a module for the some useful purpose?

Comment: *"Questions asking to recommend or find a book, tool, module, theme, distribution, tutorial, or other off-site resource are off-topic for Drupal Answers as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."* - as official close reason states. It's not *me* who says it, I only pointed this to you. There are 4 close votes now on the question, high chance it'll get closed soon.

Comment: @Mołot reallly? This rules are total nightmare, I actually find this questions and some answers really helpful...

Comment: @rukya it was like a decade ago, rules probably changed a couple of times.